# Form action called before ajax request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to validate some data using javascript, so after created this form:

```
<form asp-controller="User" asp-action="UpdateUser" asp-antiforgery="true" id="userInformations">
   <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-6 control-label">@Localizer["OldPassword"] (*)</label>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input class="form-control" required id="oldPassword"
            asp-for="@Model.ExistingPassword" type="password" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">@Localizer["NewPassword"] (*)</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input class="form-control" required id="newPassword"
                asp-for="@Model.Password" type="password" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Store</button>
</form>
```

I binded a javascript function that intercept the submit:

```
$('#userInformations').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 //validate some fields

//execute ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(true);
        console.log(result)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

});
```

Now when I press the submit button, the method `UpdateUser` in the `UserController` is called first of the javascript function, and I don't understand why happen this because I used `preventDefault`. 
How can I prevent to call the asp net action binded to the form?

Comment: Are you sure there's no JS errors? Check your developer console in your browser. What you have should work, assuming it's actually being run and the event handler is being attached correctly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt no errors, all works good the success function is called correctly but I need to execute the js first

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about then. If the form was processing as a normal form, your AJAX would never run, let alone hit the success callback, because the entire page view would change. What is it specifically that's not working?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Man is simple..  In the form I added this `asp-controller="User" asp-action="UpdateUser"` and then in the javascript I assigned a function which is firing each time the form is submitted. Now the problem is that the `preventDefault` is called but, first, is executed the function `UpdateUser` which is the function assigned to the form. I don't know why happen this.

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make sense, and restating what you already said in your question doesn't really help. Your AJAX itself is using the same URL as your form action, so server-side, the action is going to be hit either way. Are you saying it's happening *twice*?

Comment: @ChrisPratt yep, it's happening twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you want is to use javascript to validate some data , and implement the action call through ajax when you press the submit button?

I use the code you provided and it works.

Try the following two ways：

1.Add the following piece of code above your javascript

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

2.Or directly write your javascript in  **@section Scripts {  }**

Answer (score 0):

If you want JavaScript first than you have to remove asp-Controller and action from form, than you can validate form by JavaScript and send data through Ajax call to Controller/action.

Comment: could you please show me how should be wrote the ajax request in javascript if I remove the asp-Controller?

Comment: This is not correct. All this does is prevent the form from doing anything at all, which does nothing to fix the underlying issue. Additionally, it won't even work, because without explicit `asp-action` and `asp-controller` attributes, the form tag helper will simply fill in the action as the current page.